# How can I transform this integral to a simpler form?

Tags: integration

I have a function as following
$$
\operatorname{fun}(r_1,r_2,u)=\exp\left[-a \sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2u}-b(r_1^2+r_2^2-2u)-c(r_1^2+r_2^2+2u)\right]
$$
where all coefficients are real. I want to evaluate the following integral:
$$
\int_{r_1r_2}^{-r_1r_2} -\frac{1}{r_1 r_2} \operatorname{fun}(r_1,r_2,u)\, du .
$$
It seems that the second and third parts are evaluated easily but it's hard for Mathematica to evaluate the first one (involving the radical). Is there a way to evaluate the first part analytically and convert it into a simpler form?

Comment: Note that your first step is wrong. $e^{x+y}\ne e^x+e^y$

Comment: @Andrei You're right, I edited the question.

Comment: If you integrate with respect to:`u` then Mathematica can integrate.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk first I had evaluated it using Mathematica, but after that I couldn't evaluate the next integral. I asked it yesterday in Mathematica SEx . See here: [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235481/why-the-integration-command-for-this-function-gives-no-answer]